# Xcode 8, adding UIButtons to NavigationBar for non initial view controllers

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, storyboard, xcode8.2

I'm trying to achieve what I think would be a simple task, but despite similar posts on here being answered, the solution eludes me....

I'm using `Main.storyboard` in Xcode 8/swift 3 to create an application with the initial ViewController being a `UINavigationController`. I then want to push to `UITabBarController` which has two view controllers which it holds a relationship with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test") as? UITabBarController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

When launching the app, the initial ViewController successfully 'pushes' to the TabBarController/it's ViewControllers (image below). The issue I'm having is after adding navigation items/buttons in the TabBarController ViewControllers (either in Storyboard or programmatically) the buttons / nav items never show.

[Storyboard setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6129.png)

[Simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9RmB.png)

I have seen a few posts such as the below links and have followed the suggested steps verbatim, but nothing has solved the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Adding buttons to navigation controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286760/adding-buttons-to-navigation-controllers)
[How to add buttons to navigation controller visible after segueing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587465/how-to-add-buttons-to-navigation-controller-visible-after-segueing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's does not show, because your TabBarController also have his own UINavigationBar. ViewControllers are inside TabBarController

you can create custom TabBarController and handle tabs actions
Try this code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
  override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? {
    didSet {
      switch self.selectedViewController {
      case self.selectedViewController is FirstViewController:
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.firstButton
      case self.selectedViewController is SecondViewControlller:
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.secondButton
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: got it - thanks. Any recommendations on how to get them to show?